# rails bulk insert with ar-extensions: how to INSERT IGNORE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the ar-extensions gem to do bulk inserts in Rails 2.3.11 and wondering what the syntax is to insert ignore. If I just do:

```
User.import friends
```

Then I get duplicate key errors. I can try this:

```
User.import friends, :on_duplicate_key_update => [:first_name]
```

But if I don't actually want to update it then there has to be some way to just do an INSERT IGNORE. Does anybody know the proper syntax for this?

Comment: What about passing empty array to `:on_duplicate_key_update`? :-)

Comment: actually sorry seems like :on_duplicate_key_update => [:first_name] throws an error, "ArgumentError: Invalid arguments!" so that's not a valid solution in any case

Comment: So this is more of a workaround than a full answer, but it's possible to make this work by simply avoiding adding model objects to the import array that already exist in the table. In relation to the example above, this can be achieved as follows. Let's say we are populating friends by adding friend objects one by one:

    friends += [friend]

We can avoid adding troublesome objects by simply doing:

    friends += [friend] if !User.find_by_id(friend.id)

If we do this, then the issue of duplicate keys becomes moot.

Comment: Then you're making zillion of extra queries. that's what `insert ignore` was made to prevent :-)

Comment: granted, but you're still able to batch the INSERTs which is what I was going for. plus, User.find_by_id is a primary key lookup which is a pretty efficient query. I'm posting above as the answer since no one else has posted anything. It's not ideal but it's something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is more of a workaround than a full answer, but it's possible to make this work by simply avoiding adding model objects to the import array that already exist in the table. In relation to the example above, this can be achieved as follows. Let's say we are populating friends by adding friend objects one by one:

```
friends += [friend]
```

We can avoid adding troublesome objects by simply doing:

```
friends += [friend] if !User.find_by_id(friend.id)
```